# Can you buy old versions of MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

Are there legitimate companies that sell old versions of map info.  I use v9 and it will not load onto a new pc.  I don't want to buy the latest version as I fear it will be unrecognisable

Comment: v8.5 works on my Windows 10 64-bit computer. I don't have v9.0 to test.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether older versions are available, however I can allay your fears that the newer version will be unrecognisable. The latest 64-bit version of MapInfo does look significantly different with the ribbon menu bar like in the newer versions of MS Office, however you will find that the 32-bit version has not changed very much and should be very familiar to a user of v9. In terms of the functionality, both versions are very much the same with a few additions/improvements since v9. I don't think you'll have too much trouble if you upgraded to either though it may take a little bit of time to familiarise yourself with the 64-bit ribbon menu.

Answer (score 1):

As [@T_Bacon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177676/53268) said, you won't have any problem moving from v9 to v15 32-bit version. I moved from v9 straight to v12.5 32-bit.

For basic functionality, it is exactly the same, but with some great added features.

Also, depending on your needs, you may want the v15 64-bit version. Either way though, when you purchase v15 you can install one, or both of the v15 versions on the same machine at the same time. Which means the ability to run v15 32-bit and 64-bit side by side. So you can even ease yourself into the 64-bit version if it suits your needs better.